# Matplotlib Barh transitions smooth

Tags: python, matplotlib, moviepy

I'm a noob when it comes to Matplotlib and visualization in general. I've been following this tutorial: https://thecleverprogrammer.com/2020/06/23/bar-chart-race-tutorial-in-python-with-matplotlib/

Which provides a good base for solving my problems my only issue is the transitions are **very abrupt** - how would I go about adding smooth transitions like this - this is an example of how the transitions should look don't mind the actual data:
[image: Text]

As far as I'm aware - the animation function produces a frame for every interval - how can I get frames where the bars are animating over each other?

Edit:

Here's the code I'm looking at

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox
from moviepy.editor import VideoClip
from moviepy.video.io.bindings import mplfig_to_npimage

url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/johnburnmurdoch/4199dbe55095c3e13de8d5b2e5e5307a/raw/fa018b25c24b7b5f47fd0568937ff6c04e384786/city_populations'

df = pd.read_csv(url, usecols=['name', 'group', 'year', 'value'])
df.head(3)

colors = dict(zip(
    ["India", "Europe", "Asia", "Latin America", "Middle East", "North America", "Africa"],
    ["#adb0ff", "#ffb3ff", "#90d595", "#e48381", "#aafbff", "#f7bb5f", "#eafb50"]
))
group_lk = df.set_index('name')['group'].to_dict()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))


def draw_barchart(current_year):
    dff = df[df['year'].eq(current_year)].sort_values(by='value', ascending=True).tail(10)
    ax.clear()
    ax.barh(dff['name'], dff['value'], color=[colors[group_lk[x]] for x in dff['name']])
    dx = dff['value'].max() / 200
    for i, (value, name) in enumerate(zip(dff['value'], dff['name'])):
        ax.text(value-dx, i,     "   {} ({})".format(name,round(value, 2)),           size=12, color='#777777' ,weight=600, ha='left', va='center')

    ax.text(1, 0.4, current_year, transform=ax.transAxes, color='#777777', size=46, ha='right', weight=800)
    #ax.text(0, 1.06, 'Population (thousands)', transform=ax.transAxes, size=12, color='#777777')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='#777777', labelsize=12)
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.margins(0, 0.01)
    ax.grid(which='major', axis='x', linestyle='-')
    ax.set_axisbelow(True)
    ax.text(0, 1.15, 'This is a title',
            transform=ax.transAxes, size=24, weight=600, ha='left', va='top', color="#777")
    ax.text(1, 0, "My description here", transform=ax.transAxes, color='#777777', ha='right',
            bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.8, edgecolor='white'))
    plt.box(False)
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15, right=0.80, bottom=0.20, top=0.86)
    


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))
plt.show()
animator = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, draw_barchart, frames=range(1900, 2019))
animator.save('linex.gif', dpi=180, writer='imagemagick')
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code to reproduce what you're trying to do?

Comment: I've added the code @scandav

Comment: `plt.barh` does not foresee an overlap of the horizontal bars. In other words, each frame is a plot with a clear margin between bars. You won't get a smooth transition as in the gif you posted in the question.

Comment: @scandav any ideas on how I can get the bars to overlap when they transition?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, matplotlib animations do not allow for smooth transitions. It's because the graph is created and played back frame by frame. It doesn't create a graph to complement between frames. If you want to use python for bar chart tracing, there are some good dedicated libraries in python. The name of it is [bar_char_race](https://www.dexplo.org/bar_chart_race/). You can also adjust the details. Depending on the file format, you may need to pre-install ffmpeg or other software.

```
import pandas as pd
import bar_chart_race as bcr

url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/johnburnmurdoch/4199dbe55095c3e13de8d5b2e5e5307a/raw/fa018b25c24b7b5f47fd0568937ff6c04e384786/city_populations'

df = pd.read_csv(url, usecols=['name', 'group', 'year', 'value'])

df.value = df.value.astype(int)
# top 10 city
dfs = df.groupby(['group','name'],as_index=False)['value'].max().sort_values(by='value', ascending=False).head(10)
top10 = dfs.name[:10].values

dff = df.query('year >= 1900 and name in @top10')
dff = dff.pivot_table(index='year',columns='name', values='value')
dff.fillna(0, axis=1, inplace=True)
dff.index = pd.to_datetime(dff.index, format='%Y')

bcr.bar_chart_race(df=dff, n_bars=10, filename='poptop10.mp4', period_fmt='%Y')
```

[image]